# CoDeSys Visualization Dropdown Menu Custom Values in modelTextList

Tags: plc, st, codesys

Using CoDeSys, I have a drop down list for a visualization that uses an enumeration of values for the options in the list. The enumeration comes from a separate library and for my particular application I would like to use only a subset of the enumerated values in the drop-down. So in order to accomplish this, I have a text list containing only two values, 5 and 7. 
[image: Text list for drop-down elements]

This seems easy enough but when I go to run this particular drop-down I see the two values correctly but I also see numbers up to 12 for the missing IDs. 12 is weird since the enumeration has 22 enumerated values.

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to have only the two values show in the drop-down without making the ID's 0 and 1? I would really like to use the library enumeration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a checkbox that must be checked called "Filter Missing Textentries" so that the drop-down list to only contains the values given in the text list. Once that box is checked it will remove the random numbered values.

[image]